# Commerce 2 - display price summary on product pages

Tags: 8, commerce

the price is broken down in cart and checkout pages, but there is no formatter to display it this way anywhere else ... most specifically it is needed for the product detail page so customer can see product and taxes itemized (and i suppose any discounts). this seems really basic so not sure why i am not finding this answer for myself but no luck yet so asking here. thanks all